# How do I set the initial values of my UISlider and UISwitch?

Tags: ios, oop, swift

I have a class:

```
class DiscoverySettings {
    var alert:Bool
    var distance:Int
    var minAge: Int
    var maxAge: Int
    private init(){
        alert = true
        distance = 50
        minAge = 18
        maxAge = 25
    }
}
```

In another controller, I do this:

```
var discovery_model = DiscoverySettings()
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == Constants.EditDiscoverSegue {
            if let dseg = segue.destinationViewController.contentViewController as? DiscoverySettingsViewController {
                dseg.dsettings = discovery_model
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where I make my initial setting in updateUI():

```
@IBOutlet weak var distanceSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var alertSwitch: UISwitch!

var dsettings: DiscoverySettings? {
    didSet{
        updateUI()
    }
}

let ageSlider = RangeSlider(frame: CGRectZero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func updateUI(){
    self.distanceSlider.value = Float(dsettings?.distance) //error
    self.alertSwitch = dsettings?.alert //error
}
```

I get errors such as "Could not find an overload for init that accept supplied arguments" and "Could not find overload NSNumber is not a subtype of UISwitch" on the lines where I set the values.

I'm not sure why these errors are happening, since I defined the types as the same in my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
func updateUI(){
    if let dsettings = dsettings {
        self.distanceSlider?.value = Float(dsettings.distance)
        self.alertSwitch?.on = dsettings.alert
    }
}
```

Comment: Those 2 lines where I set the values.

Comment: Why do I need "if let dsettings"? Weird. If I remove that, it doesn't work.

Comment: For the answer of your question please checkout optionals and optional bindings in swift. One of the best features in the language. Also please accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: I also get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I run it. However, it compiles fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74524/discussion-between-abdullah-and-timex).

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with the code you presented:

1.: On prepareForSegue, when you set the contentViewController's settings property, the segue's destination view controller's views are not yet loaded and you are calling updateUI on didSet. This is the cause of your error:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

because the views are still nil at this point and you are automatically unwrapping the optional on the property definition because you use "!".

You should move the call to updateUI() to viewDidLoad or you must check if the views are already created

2.a: The reason you need to do "if let dsettings" is that the Float() do not accept an optional and using if let makes it so that in the if scope dsettings is no longer an optional.